# Ruby Route with dynamic data mixed in with constant routing hints

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm new to ruby and have a semi complex route that I would like to build for creating dynamic site map that lists Jobs on our website

My Controller is called SiteMap
My route location for SiteMap is 'q' for query

We have jobs by

1. Industry, e.g. Hospitality, Retail
2. Location, e.g. Sydney, Melbourne
3. Industry broken down by location, e.g. Hospitality in Sydney

Part of the URL signature is made up of constant values that d help to determine which of the three route types to use.

1. By Industry

   - www.somedomain.com/j/hosptality-jobs
   - hint: `-jobs` suffix will set the :industry param
   - `:industry => hospitality`
2. By Location

   - www.somedomain.com/j/jobs-in-sydney
   - hint: `jobs-in-` prefix will set the :location param
   - `:location => sydney`
3. By Industry and Location

   - www.somedomain.com/j/hospitality-jobs/in-sydney
   - as above but spread over 2 url segments
   - `:industry => hospitality`
   - `:location => sydney`

I either want to go to 3 different actions based on the route or I'm happy to go to one action so long as there is rich variables denoting the dynamic data and type (i.e. Type = Industry | City)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could do this is to use a catchall route:

```
get '/j/*path', to: 'jobs#route'
```

(The controller action needs a better name.)

The action reads the path using your logic and routes to the proper path with the proper parameters using `redirect_to`.

Answer (score 0):

I got all 3 routes working plus a 4th catch all route for bad URL's

```
get '/q/(:industry)-jobs' => 'sitemap#industry', :as => :sitemap_by_industry
get '/q/jobs-in-(:location)' => 'sitemap#location', :as => :sitemap_by_location
get '/q/(:industry)-jobs/in-(:location)' => 'sitemap#industry_location', :as => :sitemap_by_industry_location

# This catch is used if someone starts playing around with the URL's and we can't map to the three listed routes
get '/q(/:bad1(/:bad2))' => 'sitemap#sitemap', :as => :sitemap
```

1. www.somedomain.com/q/hosptality-jobs

   - is hitting route 1 and setting:
   - `:industry => hospitality`
2. www.somedomain.com/q/jobs-in-sydney

   - is hitting route 2 and setting:
   - `:location => sydney`
3. www.somedomain.com/q/hospitality-jobs/in-sydney

   - is hitting route 3 and setting:
   - `:industry => hospitality`
   - `:location => sydney`
4. The follwoing invalid URL's will all hit the 4th catch all route

   - www.somedomain.com/q
   - www.somedomain.com/q/
   - www.somedomain.com/q/hosptality-joXXbs
   - www.somedomain.com/q/jobXXs-in-sydney
   - www.somedomain.com/q/hospitality-jobXXs/in-sydney